# Why is it valid to say $\rho dx = \sigma$ in electromagnetism?

Tags: electromagnetism

Some problems, in electromagnetism are solved by converting a given volumetric density into a surface density. Or a surface density into a linear density. For example, and this is a procedure done by Griffiths

$$\sigma 2\pi r dr  = \lambda 2\pi r $$
$$\sigma dr = \lambda$$

What makes this valid? I've seen people consider it obvious because it has the right units, but that to me is completely misguided. I could construct all sorts of ridiculous things with the proper units...

Specifically right now I'm considering the electric field caused by a square sheet with uniform density $\sigma$. If $a$ is the sides of this square sheet, then supposedly $\sigma da/2=\lambda$. This is too strange for me to accept.

Why is it true?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes I'm sure. Why would that integral make sense though?

Comment: Well, because of the definitions of each of the densities. Each is defined in terms of length, area, volume, etc. When you multiply an area by a length, what do you get? A volume.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have 100 balls distributed evenly in a box that is one meter squared. Then the density of balls is 100 per square meter. Now to calculate the amount of balls per meter you would cut off a very thin sliver of the box and count the number of balls in the sliver. This is mathematically equivalent to multiplying sigma by da!